# cannot reset my branch to the last commit

Tags: git, github

So my issue is after I made a PR, in the review I had a commit suggestion which I commited it.
so the changes where commited directly from github, when I want to get the changes on my local it fails.
when I do :

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

or

```
git reset --hard origin/myBranch
```

it goes back to the last commit I pushed before the commit from review.

I tried to bring it with its revision

```
git checkout [revision] .
```

or

```
git reset [revision]
```

it says that that revision is unknown

error respectively

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: ...
```

and

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '0832a2c': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) first.

If you do not fetch, the commit done directly on GitHub would not be present in your repository.
Any `git reset`/`git checkout`/`git restore` would therefore fails.

After a fetch (of your PR branch), a `git reset --hard origin/myBranch` will work (make sure you don't have any local unsaved modification first).

Comment: @Bashir That is expected: you need to reset to origin/myBranch, in order to get the last fetched commit.

Comment: I already figured it out before you answer my comment (I deleted it before seeing your reply). thanks